# Delete files in .7z package

Tags: 7z

I am using FileRoller to manage the *`.7z` and using Ubuntu 12.10. When the *`.7z` file is encrypted, I can add new files to the package, I can modify text files, can I delete files too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `d` option of the `7z` tool.

#### List the contents

```
7z l <archive>  # e.g.
7z l archive.7z
```

#### Delete a file

```
7z d <archive> <file>  # e.g.
7z d archive.7z 'hello world.pdf'
```

Since you use encrypted archives the tool will prompt you for a password.

`file-roller` 3.8.4 seems to have a bug which claims a wrong password when trying to delete files from encrypted archives.